# What is topological about topologically ordered states?

Tags: condensed-matter, topological-order

My naive understanding based off section 4.8 of Nakahara's *Geometry Topology and Physics* is that topologically ordered phases are ground states that are homotopically inequivalent to other possible ground states. However, it's not clear to me why this is different from this why topologically ordered phases are different than classical phases.

Comment: You are right in that pretty much any phase is "topological" (i.e. even in very simple SSB models there is an obvious topological quantity that distinguishes the unbroken from broken phase: the number of potential wells). However topological order is a bit more special in that it does not involve breaking of 0-form symmetries, and has a whole host of defining properties (e.g. local excitations that cannot be created by localized operators) beyond this. You might want to read some of the works of Xiao-Gang Wen or John McGreevy for a better intro.

Answer (score 2):

Topological order, by definition, describe the internal order of gapped liquid state of a lattice model that does not have any symmetry (0-form, higher-form, or non-invertible). More precisely, two local lattice models with stable$^*$ gapped liquid ground states are equivalent if we can deform one lattice model to another via a path of local lattice models (which may not have any symmetry) such that the gap does not close along the path.

A topological order is an equivalence class of the above equivalence relation.

Another definition: Let $\Sigma$ be the space of lattice models with  stable$^*$ gapped liquid ground states. Topological order is an element in $\pi_0(\Sigma)$.

A lattice model with a topologically ordered ground state has the same topological order even if we add any local perturbation to the lattice model. This robustness against any local perturbations is the meaning of "topological" in the name topological order.

Thus "topological" in the name topological order and "topological" in the name topological insulator have very different meanings. See my review paper  https://browse.arxiv.org/abs/1610.03911

$^*$ The ground states is stable if the ground state degeneracy is 1 on the $n$-dimensional space whose homotopy type is $S^n$.